# Famo.us and external CSS styling

Tags: javascript, css, famo.us

I'm going through the famo.us documentation now to create a two column grid and header and footer for my site.

I'm learning that styles are set in the JavaScript object as key value pairs. I'm wondering how to still retain the ability to style via external stylesheets.

For instance:

```
layout.header.add(new Surface({
    size: [undefined, 100],
    content: "Header",
    properties: {
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        lineHeight: "100px",
        textAlign: "center"
    }
}));
```

If I want to link to a stylesheet and style it there I might say:

```
layout.header.add(new Surface({
    classes: ['header']
}));
```

And then in my CSS write:

```
.header {
    background-color: gray;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But there are other properties set in the JS object such as "size", which I would like to substitute for "height" and "width" in my stylesheet. Also, I'm wondering if I can use percentages or ems to style my application.

Any tips or references to look at would be most appreciated. Maybe there isn't a supported way to do this, since as I understand famo.us' goal is to abstract away the DOM and to do all of this work in JS. In that case I'm wondering how I can approach my projects in famo.us so that the workflow feels close to the one I'm used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is allowable in the surface properties  can be put into a style sheet class.  Size can't be, and actually don't want to put it in CSS. The whole point of using famo.us is to be able to control things like position, size and transformations via code not CSS stylesheets.  If you want to dynamically change the sizing in code, then there are many ways like using a function instead of a fixed array.

For example this code

```
new Surface({   content: content,
                size: [100, 100],
                properties: {
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(183, 232, 183)",
                    color: "rgb(51, 51, 51)",
                    fontSize:'10pt',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    paddingTop:'2pt',
                    border: '1pt solid rgb(135, 192, 140)'
                }
            });
```

Converts to

```
 new Surface({   content: content,
                size: [100, 100],
                classes:['select-button']
            });
```

css in a style sheet

```
 .select-button{
                    background-color: rgb(183, 232, 183);
                    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
                    font-size:10pt;
                    text-align: center;
                    padding-top:2pt;
                    border: 1pt solid rgb(135, 192, 140);
                }
```

hope this helps

Comment: OK, that helps me to determine that Famo.us is not the right tool for my application. It seems more geared toward building UI elements / animations rather than for building more traditional websites. Thanks for the info!